# Basic Questions About Ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

So I've been trying to study ring theory using online resources and it has been quite challenging. I really want to learn more about rings but it has been insanely frustrating so I'd like to ask if what I've learned is correct or if I am misunderstanding something.

Let R be a ring, $a,b\in R$

1: an ideal $(a)$ in $R$ is a subring that is closed under addition from any other element in itself and is closed under multiplication by any constant in $R$. $(a)$ can also be represented by the set $\left \{ ar \right. : r \in R\left.  \right \}$. The ideal $(a)$ would be called principal because it is generated by a single element

2: an element of the ideal $(a,b)$ is of the form $am+bn$ where $b,m \in R$. This ideal is not principal (unless it simplifies to a principal ideal, like if $R$ were the ring of integers it would be principal)

3: The ideal norm $N(a)=\left |  R/(a) \right |$. In the ring of imaginary quadratic numbers is there some formula to calculate the ideal norm? Ive seen somewhere that if $(a,b)=1$ (coprime), then $N(a+bi)=a^{2}+b^{2}$. Is there a generalization of this?

4: Ideal multiplication I'm shaky on. From intuition here is what I think:
$(a)(b)=(ab)$. If my intuition is correct, then $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,ad,bc,bd)$. From this logic, I'd think that $(a)+(b)=(a,b)$ but I dont think this is right

5: In a quotient ring $R/(a,b)$, $a=0$ and $b=0$

Thanks a lot for any help! Any resources (clear) would be very much appreciated aswell.

Comment: Be careful, an ideal is not a subring, unless you authorize rings without unit. It is true by definition that $(a)+(b)=(a,b)$, and $(a)(b)=(ab)$ is also correct.

Comment: Oh my bad I was probably thinking of subset. And thank you-did you spot any problems with the other points?

Comment: In general posts that are a list of loosely connected statements you think are true which ask "am I right about all of these?" are not going to go over well. Maybe it can be resolved this way. 1,2,4,5 are all correct. In 4, I think you're right about $(ac,ad,bc,bd)$, but that doesn't seem useful or necessary to prove $(a)+(b)=(a,b)$. So perhaps you could drop all the points but 3), which actually poses a question that people can tackle.

Comment: Re: 4 again also: there are lots of posts about ideal multiplication. Search around a bit and you should be able to find them.

Comment: @rschwieb I just wanted to ensure that my intuition was correct because I don't want to continue studying relying on false knowledge

Comment: @uhhhhidk I understand that :) And I think a better way would be to strike up a conversation in the Mathematics chat room for this site. They can dispel doubts like these quickly.  Posting things like that can cause a little friction though, since the posts are supposed to be longer lived and more functional (and not ephemeral, as 1,2,4,5 are going to be in this case.) At any rate, I've given a complete answer to those four questions in the comments. So do they really need to live on in the post to distract everyone from the remaining question?